# Can I change HDD PCB to try fixing a dead HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata

I have a Seagate Barracuda Compute HDD (3TB) that just died because I used a borrowed PSU that wasn't turning on when SATA was plugged, after I switched cables and everything it didn't turn on again, tried 2 different motherboards (2 desktops), different SATA cables and different PSU SATA cables, the HDD ain't being recognized by the computer.

My dead HDD is the following:
[3TB Barracuda HDD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pi8n0.jpg)

and I have a working HDD the same model, but with only 1TB.

If I change the PCB from the working hard drive and replace it in the dead hard drive, could it fix my dead HDD so I can access its data? Could this result in any problem for the working hard drive?

Comment: Is the drive spinning up, or remaining silent when plugged in?

Comment: This is only to be done if you don't value your data to the cost of professional recovery as its likely to make things worse - I have a Baraccuda drive which I removed the PCB from, and I see a lot of resistors/resistor/diode like things (fuses ?) connected from the underside of the power connector - see if any of them are burnt out and either replace them or short them.  (You may want to take a picture and ask for help in electronics.se) - Again, this is more likely to make things worse then better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement board must be from an identical drive. There are also specific numbers on the board that must match, the details of which depending on the drive model. Two apparently identical drives may have come from different factories and have significant internal differences. In addition, the original board will have an integrated circuit containing drive specific information which must be transferred to the new board. Unless this is done properly there is virtually no chance of the drive working and you may corrupt existing data. Unless you have experience with this kind of thing it would be best to have it done by a professional. This would be done only for the purposes of data recovery and not for continued use of the drive.

I have not done this but have only read about it.

Answer (score 1):

It will definitely cost more, but data recovery services, like drivesavers, have inventories of circuit boards, and know exactly what they are doing.

I suggest let a professional do the work.

Answer (score 0):

This is unlikely, as the firmware on the board most likely is not compatible.  It might be worth a go as a last-ditch effort though.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for me to do before trying it then?

Comment: I’ve never had this work. From what I understand there is a low level format that is performed by the board at the manufacturer. They are mated together and swapping them simply will not work.